# Custom static blocks in magento 1.9.0.1 home page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme

I am converting an *HTML template into Magento theme*. Here I have to separate each blocks into custom static block files such as `footermenu.phtml`, `tweet.phtml` and `copyright.phtml` to call like,

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footermenu'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tweet'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('copyright'); ?>
```

After reading [**this blog tutorial**](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/), added a new block like the following but it is not appearing with my `Magento 1.9.0.1`

**`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference" translate="label">
                <label>New Reference</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="newreference">
            <block type="core/template" name="newreferenceblock" template="newreference.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </layout>
```

In **`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml`**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreference') ?>
```

**`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template/newreference.phtml`**

```
<h1 style="background-color:yellow">Hello New Reference!</h1>
```

Comment: from which position you want add this block <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footermenu'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tweet'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('copyright'); ?> ?

Comment: @AmitBera Actually it is for splitting footer part. Same thing I need for other sections also.For example: ourservices, top sellers,etc.

Comment: are yo want to show only home?

Comment: @AmitBera No. I want to display this in all pages as common.

Comment: @AmitBera If you don't mind, please explain both in your answer (showing only in home, in all pages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want   add this blocks  to home  page then you need to add this template under cms_index_index hadler:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
    <cms_index_index> <!-- add home page handler for showing on home page -->
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference" translate="label">
                <label>New Reference</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="core/template" name="footermenu" template="page/template/footermenu.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="tweet" template="page/template/tweet.phtml" />
    <block type="core/template" name="copyright" template="page/template/copyright.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
    </layout>
```

if want to `show it at all pages then change handler  cms_index_index to default`

As your reference block name is footer then it need add code at  footer.phtml

**[Edit need]** because getChildHtml() not exit for class  render all chld phtml file of footer.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footermenu'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tweet'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('copyright'); ?>
```

More details at

http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/30/introducing-magento-layout/

You have to put your child template files in `app/design/frontend/[base]/[default]/template/`

Comment: Now the block is adding when I enable ``Template Path Hints`` but the page contents are not rendering here.

Comment: can you put footer.phtml code?

Comment: footer.phtml ``...?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footermenu'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tweet'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('copyright'); ?> ``

Comment: copyright.phtml ``<h1>Am from Copyright!</h1>``

Comment: remove it.previously footermenu.phtml.phtml  need to change to footermenu.phtml

Comment: footer is in html folder and others are in template folder

Comment: already changed footermenu.phtml.phtml to footermenu.phtml

Comment: clear cache?it should works as $this->getChildHtml()  exits. which render all child of footer

Comment: I have disabled all cache, it showing the block separation in debug mode. But no content. Now flush all cache from admin also.

Comment: footermenu.phtml, tweet.phtml and copyright.phtml file location?

Comment: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/

Comment: $this->getChildHtml() exits in footer.phtml?

Comment: Sorry, those file location is app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template/ and the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/footer.phptml content ``<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footermenu'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tweet'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('copyright'); ?> ``

Comment: ckd now/................

Comment: This is working fine when I copied this to main template folder ``app/design/frontend/base/default/template/`` instead of ``app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template/``. Can you update the answer to use file from ``app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template/`` or ``app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/``? And also please explain using a custom block without including in available blocks like footer.

Comment: template will take path upvto app/design/frontend/base/default/template/  and need rest of file path

Comment: Sure. If you have time, can you explain using custom block without referring footer in the answer?

Comment: need to study http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts